# The view user.views.profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UpdateUserForms, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UpdateUserForms(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save() 
            messages.success(request, f'Your account is updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
        
        else:
            u_form = UpdateUserForms(instance=request.user)
            p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

            context = {
                'u_form': u_form,
                'p_form': p_form
            }
        return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

The view user.views.profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

this error is occuring

Comment: What if `request.method` is not `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that you're rendering a response only in case the method is `POST` as being seen here:

```py
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
        return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

but loading a page is considered a `GET` request, just unindent the `return render(...)` line like this:

```py
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Comment: thanks for help I just double tabbed in else statement

Comment: How to solve this error with **UpdateView**?